# Case Email Attachments

Tags: soql, case, attachment

I am trying to retrieve attachments for emails on a specific case using SOQL and not having much success. I am trying using following

```
Select id, Name, Body, ContentType, parentId from Attachment where parentId in (select (select id from EmailMessages) from Case where Id = '5005700001Oz5na')
```

I get unknown parsing error I guess because of the inner select statement. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Whoa! Your soql looks confusing. First you can't have nested sub queries ( child access allowed to single child level) and then even your sub query looks incorrect. Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) link for soql relationship basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a sub-query in a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com). If you want to get `Attachment` records looking up to `EmailMessage` records under a specific `Case`, you would use a direct query on `EmailMessage` in your join filter:

```
SELECT ... FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN (
    SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage WHERE ParentId = '5005700001Oz5na'
)
```